# Skipped iCloud Keychain configuration during install of El Capitan

Tags: install, keychain, macos

During installation of El Capitan I skipped the iCloud Keychain configuration because it wouldn't validate the code sent to my phone.

What was this process for and how do I restart it now that the instillation is complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Settings > iCloud > Keychain. You should be able to set it up from ther. Make sure your phone is also on iOS 9.

Comment: I only have iPhone 4.

Comment: I see, its a password manager.